# Missing TSC warning for invalid assignment

Tags: typescript, tsc

I'm trying to write a TypeScript type definition file for the [node-serialport](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport) library. The library exports a `parsers` variable with two functions, `raw` and `readline`. The latter cannot be used as a parser directly - it produces a parser when invoked. This is a fragment of my first attempt at a type definition file:

```
/// <reference path="./node.d.ts" />
declare module "serialport" {

    import events = module("events");
    export interface ParserFunc {
        (eventEmitter: events.NodeEventEmitter, buffer: NodeBuffer): void;
    }

    interface Parsers {
        raw: ParserFunc;
        readline(delimiter?: string): ParserFunc;
    }

    export var parsers: Parsers;
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that tsc doesn't warn if I assign `parsers.readline` to a variable of `ParserFunc` type. To illustrate, consider the following TypeScript file:

```
import sp = module("serialport");

var a: number = sp.parsers.raw; // not ok
var b: number = sp.parsers.readline; // not ok
var c: sp.ParserFunc = sp.parsers.raw; // ok!
var d: sp.ParserFunc = sp.parsers.readline; // not ok
```

When I compile/transpile this file using tsc, I get:

```
test1.ts(3,16): Cannot convert 'sp.ParserFunc' to 'number'
test1.ts(4,16): Cannot convert '(delimiter?: string) => sp.ParserFunc' to 'number'
```

But no warning for the assignment to `d`! If I make the `delimiter` parameter of `readline` required by removing the `?`, I get:

```
test1.ts(3,16): Cannot convert 'sp.ParserFunc' to 'number'
test1.ts(4,16): Cannot convert '(delimiter: string) => sp.ParserFunc' to 'number'
test1.ts(6,23): Cannot convert '(delimiter: string) => sp.ParserFunc' to 'sp.ParserFunc': Call signatures of types '(delimiter: string) => ParserFunc' and 'ParserFunc' are incompatible:
    Type 'String' is missing property 'addListener' from type 'NodeEventEmitter'
```

So NOW it detects that the assignment to `d` is invalid. But why not before?

This is my first encounter with TypeScript whatsoever, so please be gentle. Thanks! :-)

Comment: The assignment won't result in an error because you're declaring both properties of type ParserFunc. However, the second declaration (readline) actually means: "I have a function which has an optional string as input and which will return me something of type ParserFunc"

Comment: @Anzeo the type of `sp.parsers.readline` is `(delimiter?: string) => serialport.ParserFunc` not `serialport.ParserFunc` so it should error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does look like a bug to me. It looks like the compiler has assumed you are calling the function when you aren't.

I can recreate this with the simplified example:

```
declare module serialport {

    export interface ParserFunc {
        (eventEmitter: number, buffer: string): void;
    }

    interface Parsers {
        raw: ParserFunc;
        readline(delimiter?: string): ParserFunc;
    }

    export var parsers: Parsers;
}

var c: serialport.ParserFunc = serialport.parsers.raw; // ok!
var d: serialport.ParserFunc = serialport.parsers.readline; // not ok
```

So if readline was actually called, this would be valid - but actually readline is being passed without being called so it should show an error.

You can raise bugs on the [TypeScript Codeplex website](http://typescript.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Yep, this is a bug. I've raised this with the team, but feel free to log a CodePlex bug if you want to track the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I'll file a bug report!